# Aurelia Value Converters using array

Tags: aurelia

I have a question with Value Converters, I have an array w/c filters inactive item, when I am editing an item and change the status property to 'INACTV', the table does not change. but when adding/removing items in the array, it refreshes, my workaround is creating a binded _signal property to force the filtering, is there a way not to do this?

< tr repeat.for="item of ARRAY | filtercustom:'STATUS_CD':'INACTV':_signal" >

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood how the filter is supposed to work. But if it should hide inactive items, maybe you could do something like

```
<tr repeat.for="item of ARRAY" if.bind="!item.STATUS_CD='INACTV'">
```

I don't know if it is possible to put a value converter inside a "repeat.for". Looks weird.

I hope this helps to push you in the right direction.

Comment: i tried your suggestion. but it only works on first time the array has been filled. If i remove the item in the array, the table view refreshes. But my purpose is changing the property STATUS_CD to INACTIVE, so the item will be hidden on the view. I know it its a dirty work using Value Converters. any other suggestion other than using it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no direct, clean way to do this at the moment. Repeat.for uses a `CollectionObserver` for array observation which only responds to pop/push/reverse/shift/sort/splice/unshift.

Only when one of these methods is called on the array, the observer fires and the array is fed to your `ValueConverter` again.

Your signal solution is about as clean as it gets. It's more efficient than the alternative of refreshing the whole array from manually instantiated property observers on your `STATUS_CD` property on every item in the array.
Which is what I do in some similar situations, because I don't like using signals. But that's just a matter of preference.